# MFC: Ring - no color change

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to learn MFC from book: MV C++ Windows Application by Example(2008). There is example app. where I can draw rings filled witch chosen color:

```
void CRingView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
CRingDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
if (!pDoc)
    return;
PointArray& pointArray = pDoc->GetPointArray();
ColorArray& colorArray = pDoc->GetColorArray();
int iSize = static_cast<int>(pointArray.GetSize());
for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < iSize; iIndex++)
{
    CPoint point = pointArray[iIndex];
    COLORREF color = colorArray[iIndex];
    CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 0, BLACK);
    CBrush brush(color);
    pDC->Ellipse(point.x - RADIUS, point.y - RADIUS, point.x + RADIUS, point.y + RADIUS);
    CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&pen);
    CBrush* pOldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&brush);
}
}
```

but there is no color change(always white like bg) even if I do:

```
CBrush brush(BLACK);
```

So question is: What I'm doing wrong? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 but with new project there shouldn't be any compatibility errors.
And BLACK is:

```
static const COLORREF BLACK = RGB(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Try selecting the pen and brush before you do the ellipse drawing.

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks it worked with: 'CBrush brush(color);
  pDC->SelectObject(brush);
  pDC->Ellipse...' - do you ad it as answer or we leave it as it is?

Comment: Glad it worked. I've added the comment as an answer so that you don't have unanswered questions against your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DC draws with whatever brush, pen, font, etc. objects are currently selected. So `SelectObject` of the pen and the brush should happen before doing the drawing.